# How to integrate a composite function with a variable exponent?

Tags: calculus

Is there a general formula, or any "tools",  for solving
$$\int f(x)^n \, dx $$ ?
I apologize if this is a basic question... but I am trying to remember my calculus, and even with searching online and through the archives here, I can't figure this one out.  I'm looking for just a general formula (such as I know exists for differentiation).  Or, I can make some restrictions, such as $n$ is positive, and $f(x)$ is always between 0 and 1.

Comment: Not in general. Did you have any specific function $f$ in mind?

Comment: Not really -- I was just wondering if I was missing some general rule that would make my life easier.  Though most I care about are polynomials like $f(x) = 1-x$ or $f(x) = x-x^2$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is linear, then you can always do a substitution so that you end up with something like $\int u^n \mathrm du$.

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial, then $f^n$ is a polynomial too. Just multipy everything out and integrate termwise (except if $f$ is of degree one; then it's better to follow J. M.'s hint).

Comment: @Hans: but how can you multiply it out if you don't know what $n$ is?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be difficult in general. $\int(\arctan\,x)^2\;\mathrm dx$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, for instance.

---

If the $f(x)$ in $\int f(x)^n \mathrm dx$ is a polynomial, things are a little easier. As Hans mentions in the comments, one can in general use the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) to expand out the integrand into chunks that are slightly easier to integrate, but one should watch out for approaches that are more convenient for manipulation, e.g. if $f(x)$ is in fact the power of some binomial.

For linear and quadratic $f(x)$, some preliminary manipulations can be done so that one does not require the full generality of the multinomial theorem. For instance, if $f(x)=ax+b$, one can do the following:

$$\int(ax+b)^n \mathrm dx=a^n\int\left(x+\frac{b}{a}\right)^n \mathrm dx$$

and letting $u=x+\frac{b}{a}$, we have

$$a^n\int u^n\mathrm du=a^n\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{(ax+b)^{n+1}}{a(n+1)}$$

For $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, one can "complete the square" like so (see anything familiar?):

$$\int(ax^2+bx+c)^n \mathrm dx=a^n\int\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}\right)^n \mathrm dx=a^n\int\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}\right)^n \mathrm dx$$

from which one can (repeatedly) use the (probably more familiar) binomial theorem instead of the multinomial theorem for the expansion.